# Which event will be called first when bubbling is stopped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

After capturing, bubbling will be executed but what will happen when I called `stopPropagation()` in bubbling phase?

will event execution flow change?

```js
var element1 = document.getElementsByClassName('element1')[0],
  element2 = document.getElementsByClassName('element2')[0],
  element3 = document.getElementsByClassName('element3')[0],
  foo = function(e) {
    console.log(this.className);
  },
  stop = function(e) {
    console.log('prevent', this.className);
    e.preventDefault();
  },
  stop1 = function(e) {
    console.log('stop', this.className);
    e.stopPropagation();
  };

element1.addEventListener('click', foo); // bubbling
element1.addEventListener('click', foo, true); // caputring
// You cab change handler to "stop"
element2.addEventListener('click', foo);
element2.addEventListener('click', foo, true);
element3.addEventListener('click', stop1);
element3.addEventListener('click', foo, true);
```

```css
.element1 {
  background-color: #b0c4de;
  height: 160px;
  width: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.element2 {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50px;
}

.element3 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Please open Chrome console and click element3</h3>
<div class="element1">element1
  <div class="element2">element2
    <div class="element3">element3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/je1g3f29/1137/)

For above one expected output is

```
element1
element2
element3
stop element3
```

Output is

```
element1
element2
stop element3
element3
```

Answer (score 1):

`stopPropagation` prevents further propagation of the current event. Propagation means if you go from on element to the next (not form on event listener to the next). The `element3` in this case is neither in the bubbling nor in the capturing phase, but in the target phase:

[3. DOM Event Architecture](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow)

> - The **capture phase**: The event object propagates through the **target’s ancestors** from the Window to the target’s parent. This phase is also known as the capturing phase.
> - The **target phase**: The event object arrives at the event object’s event target. This phase is also known as the at-target phase. If the event type indicates that the event doesn’t bubble, then the event object will halt after completion of this phase.
> - The **bubble phase**: The event object propagates through the **target’s ancestors** in reverse order, starting with the target’s parent and ending with the Window. This phase is also known as the bubbling phase.

So if you are in the **target phase** then it does not really matter if the event handler is attached as bubbling or as capturing, because there is no propagation to another element at the transition from capturing to bubbling. So the eventhandlers are exectued in the order they where attached ignoring the phase flag.

So if you call `stopPropagation` it will prevent the propagation to the next element, but all event listeners of `element3` no matter if they where added using `useCapture` or not are called.

Answer (score -1):

switch the place of eventlisteners on element 3 like this

```
element2.addEventListener('click', foo, true);
 element3.addEventListener('click', foo, true);
 element3.addEventListener('click', stop1);
```

Comment: That will give the output the OP expects, but does not explain why. The OP expects `stop1` to be called after `foo` because `stop1` is registered for the bubbling and `foo` for the capturing phase, so to the understanding of the OP the order in which the `addEventListener` should not matter. As of that you have to explain why it does matter in this case.